# Eigen sparse matrix. setFromTriplets, algorithms instead of arrays

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I wrote a program, with custom arrays and custom operators, which saves a lot of memory.

If I use these custom arrays there is no issue, except from the fact that I still need to reserve space:

```
vector<Eigen::Triplet<double>> tripletList;
tripletList.reserve(size_nnz)
for (int=0; i < size_nnz; i++) {
    tripletList.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(rows[i], cols[i], vals[i]))
}
```

What I want is just to write 3 arrays. Not vectors, just arrays (they are custom array anyway).

Then say to the program:

These are the arrays, use them.
Without any fancy push_back, reserve or anything.

The main issue is that I wrote these array in a way to not use memory (they are algorithm but they work fine nevertheless).
So reserving the space is useless.

And no, the space each of those 3 arrays occupy is different. Some of them are plain algorithms, others have just few elements allocated.

In the end they obviously have the same "virtual" length. So you can scroll them from 0 to nnz-1 using a for loop and an index.

### Addendum 1:

I use mkl with fortran.
The spicy lines are these:

```
! initialization
real(8),allocatable :: val_arr(:)
integer(8),allocatable :: col_arr(:), row_arr(:)

!allocation
allocate(row_arr(nnz),col_arr(nnz),val_arr(nnz))

! filling arrays [....]

!sparse matrix creation
stat = mkl_sparse_d_create_coo(sp_matrix, SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE, N, N,&
    nnz, row_arr, col_arr, val_arr)
```

I can't pass him customized array, from what I understand.
I can do it in C++ (tried it out), but the thing that bothers me is the statement:

```
    vector<Eigen::Triplet<double>> tripletList;
    tripletList.reserve(nnz);
```

Where we allocate 3 * nnz * sizeof(double) If I understand the meaning of this.

I just want to allocate these 3 arrays (each of different memory consumption in the C++ program, but with the same index range) and say to Eigen:
These are the arrays. Use them

Comment: You can pass any iterators to `setFromTriplets()` as long as their `value_type` provides a `value()`, `row()` and `col()`.

Comment: It isn't abundantly clear to me: Do you want to initialize from a fancy iterator like a [`zip_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_transform_view) generating triplets? Do you want to initialize by [mapping your arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192340/how-do-i-initialize-a-eigen-sparse-matrix-with-a-values-innerindices-outersta/75192521#75192521)? Or do you want a custom expression that acts like a sparse matrix, e.g. similar to how [`SparseView`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/SparseView_8h_source.html) adapts a dense matrix for sparse evaluation?

Comment: I still need to read more into zip_view. However what I need is just to pass something that acts like an array to Setfromtriplets without reserving any space in Setfromtriplets itself. In mkl, for example, you just create these arrays and put them as arguments of your sparse_matrix. I want to do so even here, allocating memory only when initializing the arrays themselves, and not when initializing tripletList. I want tripletList to know only the maximum index it can use, so the "virtual" size of these arrays, so nnz.

Comment: @Mitto Please show the code that you use with MKL. I think this would make it a lot clearer

Comment: I added a section to the question regarding the code

Comment: Eigen supports CSC and CSR matrix formats but not COO. You are probably better off converting to one of the supported formats, either via triplets or direct inserts. In theory you can create an adaptor similar to `SparseView` but I don't think that's worth the effort. Of course if you start out with your arrays forming a CSC or CSR matrix, both MKL and Eigen can directly use your arrays

Comment: can you link me some documentation? I can't find how on eigen. In addition I still need to understand the difference between the 3 formats: if you have something for this too I'm really grateful. thanks

Comment: If I use setfromTriplets, it actually works as a coo format. Am I right? That's why I was interested in using it without allocating memory in it. The algorithm for the csr version of the 3 arrays would be more complicated (I didn't even try and I still need to understand how it works, even if I have the documentation in front of me now)

Comment: MKL documents all three formats [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-c/2023-1/sparse-matrix-storage-formats.html#MKL_APPA_SMSF_5), Eigen [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html). Instead of going through triplets, you can also call [`matrix.insert(row, col) = value`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#ae2d8f72ff86a300b76f9edd67df8d8fd) for each value. As long as the indices are sorted, it is very fast

Comment: Side-note: Please write @username when responding. Commenters don't get notifications for new comments unless they are mentioned.

Comment: @Homer512 I read the Eigen documentation, but I thought it was an explicit csr or csc format such as the one used to create the sparse matrix in MKL. matrix.insert() is fast indeed. The fastest of the ones i tried. However I can save some memory when writing the arrays for row, columns and nnz values because I can write the arrays as functors and use some algorithm to define them. That's why i was interested in a way to use setfromtriplets method without the tripletlist.reserve() as i think it reserves nnz bytes for each of the arrays.

Comment: If it's just an overall extimation of the memory used by all these 3 arrays it's ok, but i think that's not the case. Let us assume the custom array i wrote for value_array allocates x doubles, for row_array allocates nnz-x doubles and for column_array allocates 0 doubles. Am I able to put them inside tripletlist and use it in setfromtriplets if i want to reserve x + nnz-x + 0 doubles?

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. For starters, your row and column arrays are ints, not doubles. And a triplet is two ints and a double, so 16 byte. Anyway, if `insert` works for you, why not use it rather than triplets? If you call `mat.reserve(nnz)` beforehand, insert in sorted order, and then call `mat.makeCompressed()` it is very fast and uses the least amount of memory since you don't need the temporary triplet array.

Comment: Because I need to do so

Comment: I like to say the context again, cause I want to do it this way. I have algorithms to compute row_arr, col_arr and val_arr. I do not have easy algorithm for the entire matrix. I need to pass him row_arr, col_arr, val_arr. Instead of writing 3 arrays and copying then in tripletList, I want to pass them directly. Instead of allocating memory in tripletList, I want to allocate it in the arrays. I can define custom arrays which return value allocated or value computed based on the index required. They have different bytes allocated and the same index range.