# Kronecker sparse product

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, intel-mkl, kronecker-product

I found these:

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/classEigen_1_1KroneckerProductSparse.html
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/classEigen_1_1KroneckerProductBase.html

However I'm wondering if i can put csr or coo arrays directly into it.
Not going through insert, set from triplets etc, cause i peeked inside those and a lot of things happen.

Something simple like this class:

```
class sparse_matrix_csr{
    public: 
    uint size;
    double *nnz_arr;
    int *col_arr;
    int *row_arr;

    //Row Major order
    sparse_matrix_csr(uint size_ext){ //constructor
        size = size_ext;
        nnz_arr = ALLOCATE_ARRAY(double, size*size*size);
        col_arr = ALLOCATE_ARRAY(int, size*size*size);
        row_arr = ALLOCATE_ARRAY(int, (size*size)+1 );
    }  
};
```

(Currently working on the destructor cause I'm always bad at these grammar-like things and chat-gpt doesn't aknowledge the existence of malloc).

Simple arrays are faster if you just need to create them and delete them.

So, i created an algorithm to give the 3 csr arrays i need for the initial sparse matrices (mkl documentation explains them. I think they are different from Eigen Inner and Outer Indices though), but i can rewrite it to give other formats too. I will put them inside an arpack diagonalizator, so csr should be better though, as i have that, coo or csc choices. There is no overlap with eigen, as they don't provide lanczos algorithms (they are provided by one library built upon it though, but that's a totally different usecase and style of writing).

So: is it possible to do so without rewriting all the algorithm, or is there something I could base this one on?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192340/how-do-i-initialize-a-eigen-sparse-matrix-with-a-values-innerindices-outersta/75192521#75192521) for mapping an existing CSR matrix into Eigen? Eigen doesn't support COO matrices.

Comment: What is the (intended) difference between your `sparse_matrix_csr` and `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor, int>` (from your question it appears, like you try to re-design this)? If you have an existing (CSR) sparse matrix from another library, you can interact with Eigen using `Map<SparseMatrix<...> >` as suggested by @Homer512. In that case the existing library would be responsible for memory management. I suggest not to rely on Chat-GPT to design classes (including memory management), if you don't understand yourself what is happening.

Comment: yes, if you want to write map as answer, I'll accept that: that's what i was looking for. (I was assuming csr as the 3 arrays version of the one presented at the beginning of eigen documentation. Regarding chatgpt is useful for grammar like issue. I'm not a skilled computer scientist when it comes to know the right sentence to write (just like I didn't know about map).

Comment: Well, if my other answer solves your issue, just close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Where do i need to click?